# Ralink RT2870 Help. Drivers installed but device incorrectly only showing 1 available wireless essid

Tags: drivers, ralink

The state of my wireless connection is what drove me a Linux newbie, but an enthusiast, to plunge my beak in deep waters, hoping to catch that fish.

Here is the deal, I have an inbuilt rtl8192ee as a wireless card, as many would be aware the driver support by Realtek is horrible for Linux (dont know why?), so i decided to skip the wait for a better upgrade in the latter versions of distros, and went with a usb wireless adapter. Ralink rt2870. I have compiled and install the drivers with great difficulty ( I had to upgrade from 14.04 to 15.10 Wily, unwittingly, I was hoping do release-upgrade would get to the next chronological update, 14.10 but then it didnt stop there..)

I have installed the module in the kernel using mod probe, I see the wifi when  I do iwconfig. (ra0) BUT,when I do

iwlist ra0 scan : It only returns one network available, while my onboard realtek shows around 15 available. It is strange, and am unable to find any support on the website of ralink for their chipsets, I am almost sure that I got the drivers part done correctly.

Dont know where to look for, for a solution. Please help.

PS: I have blacklisted the rt2xxusb and others..

Teja

Answer (score 0):

Solved it!!

It turns out my home Wifi was broadcasting on channel 13, but my device was configured to capture from channels 1 to 11. Strange , but anyway I am elated. 
I just reset my Wifi to broadcast on channel 1-11, and Voila, problem solved.Took me a while this..

Cheers